# Expand a list of dictionaries into a readable format

Tags: python, python-2.7

My description/title may be lacking, as I am new to python, however as an example, I currently have data like below stored in the variable `bunnies`:

> [{'rabbithole': {'holenumber': 1, 'family': 'roger', 'status': 'elite'},
>   'food': 'steak', 'children': 108, 'job': 'chef', 'etc': 'etc', 'etc':
>   'etc'}, {'rabbithole': {'holenumber': 2, 'family': 'roger', 'status':
>   'elite'}, 'food': 'steak', 'children': 108, 'job': 'chef', 'etc': 'etc',
>   'etc': 'etc'}, {'rabbithole': {'holenumber': 3, 'family': 'roger',
>   'status': 'elite'}, 'food': 'steak', 'children': 108, 'job': 'chef',
>   'etc': 'etc', 'etc': 'etc'}]

my goal is to break it into a readable format like this:

```
{
'rabbithole': {
    'holenumber': 1,
    'family': 'roger', 
    'status': 'elite'
}, 
'food': 'steak', 
'children': 108, 
'job': 'chef', 
'etc': 'etc', 
'etc': 'etc'
}

...
```

What I have so far is this...

```
def virt(list):
    for i in list:
        print i
        print "\n"

virt(bunnies)
```

which gives me a new line for each rabbithole listing...

so I tried this:

```
import re
def virt(list)
    for i in list:
        match = re.search( r'{|.*: {.*},|.*:.*,|}',i, re.I)
        print i.replace(match,match+"\n")

virt(bunnies)
```

Unfortunately this didn't do anything except throw an error from the re library.

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 146, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
```

I haven't looked too much into that error yet, but I have a feeling I was going in the wrong direction anyway.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: you should view `pprint` module if you just look for pretty printing

Comment: Ill take a look into this too, thanks ozy

Comment: the json module breaks up the {} a bit better, but this one is a bit more simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) Python module:

```
import json

print json.dumps(your_data, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Example:

```
a=json.dumps([{'rabbithole': {'holenumber': 1, 'family': 'roger', 'status': 'elite'}, 'food': 'steak', 'children': 108, 'job': 'chef', 'etc': 'etc', 'etc': 'etc'}, {'rabbithole': {'holenumber': 2, 'family': 'roger', 'status': 'elite'}, 'food': 'steak', 'children': 108, 'job': 'chef', 'etc': 'etc', 'etc': 'etc'}, {'rabbithole': {'holenumber': 3, 'family': 'roger', 'status': 'elite'}, 'food': 'steak', 'children': 108, 'job': 'chef', 'etc': 'etc', 'etc': 'etc'}], sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
>>> print a
[
    {
        "children": 108,
        "etc": "etc",
        "food": "steak",
        "job": "chef",
        "rabbithole": {
            "family": "roger",
            "holenumber": 1,
            "status": "elite"
        }
    },
    {
        "children": 108,
        "etc": "etc",
        "food": "steak",
        "job": "chef",
        "rabbithole": {
            "family": "roger",
            "holenumber": 2,
            "status": "elite"
        }
    },
    {
        "children": 108,
        "etc": "etc",
        "food": "steak",
        "job": "chef",
        "rabbithole": {
            "family": "roger",
            "holenumber": 3,
            "status": "elite"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: スゲー or in English, holy cow... simple and to the point... I need to look into the json library a bit more...